# NoMethodError: undefined method new for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m facing a problem when trying to enter the `list = list.new` in the rails console. I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new’ for nil:NilClass
from /Users/csamanian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing’
from (irb):1
from /Users/csamanian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start’
from /Users/csamanian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start’
from /Users/csamanian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `’
from script/rails:6:in `require’
from script/rails:6:in `’
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you post model/controller for 'list'?

Answer (score 5):

Model names are capitalized by convention in Rails.  Try this instead:

```
list = List.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
@list = List.new
```